# Dumping a JSON using tab indents (not spaces)

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I know how to dump a JSON string using spaces. This is the command I'm currently using to prettify and dump a JSON string:

```
json.dump(data, open('dev_integrated.json', 'w'), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

I wanted to know if there was a way to specify indent of 1 tab instead of 4 spaces. I wasn't able to look this up in the docs anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can't do that, but you can replace 4 spaces in the resulting string with tab in a separate call

Comment: You could use `simplejson` here, it has some nice features on top of what `json` module provides. Another option is to copy [the changes](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/b643ef8f8e92728c2a4afaaa860592e384c7178c) and [create a custom class](http://ideone.com/A7injH).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks. I'll take a look. Seems interesting.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### Python 2.7

there is a workaround that can be implemented using regular expressions :

```
import re
dump = json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
#Replaces spaces with tab
new_data = re.sub('\n +', lambda match: '\n' + '\t' * (len(match.group().strip('\n')) / 3), dump)
json.dump(new_data, open('dev_integrated.json', 'w')
```

#### Python 3.2+

From the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) :

> If indent is a non-negative integer or string, then JSON array elements and object members will be pretty-printed with that indent level. An indent level of 0, negative, or "" will only insert newlines. None (the default) selects the most compact representation. Using a positive integer indent indents that many spaces per level. If indent is a string (such as "\t"), that string is used to indent each level.

Hence the TAB-indentation can be implemented as follows:

```
json.dump(jString, open('dev_integrated.json', 'w'), sort_keys=True, indent='\t', separators=(',', ': '))
```

Comment: The question is tagged Python 2.7. This is Python 3.2+ specific feature.

Comment: Sorry, realised the name `jString` was a misnomer here. Edited your post. ;)

Comment: So I tried your method. Had to change the last line to: `print >> open('dev_integrated.json', 'w'), new_data` Otherwise it would dump preserving the characters as is. But this is good enough. Thanks.

Comment: The / 3 doesn't match the number of indented spaces, it should be 4. And use // instead of /. But this division is not necessary when json.dumps uses indent=1. Also the search for \n can be avoided using ^ at the beginning of pattern and flags=re.MULTILINE